# Operating Ms Paint using excel-VBA

Tags: excel, paint, vba

I've written a code to copy the charts from a worksheet (in my excel workbook) to Ms-Paint and then saving the results.

```
Sub paintCharts()
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DesiredData").Activate
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.ShapeRange.Group
    .CopyPicture
    .Ungroup
End With
Dim path_Paint As String
Dim paintID As Variant
path_Paint = "C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe"
paintID = Shell(path_Paint, vbNormalFocus)
Call AppActivate(paintID)
Call SendKeys("^V")
End Sub
```

I am getting an error at the `Call AppActivate(paintID)` further, I want to ask if by calling `Call SendKeys("^V")` and then `Call SendKeys("^S")` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be saved by paint?  You can save charts themselves directly.

Just use

```
Set objChart = ActiveChart 
objChart.Export ("filename.jpg")
```

Though looking at the date, I assume you figured it out by now...

Comment: Where does it export to? Current directory?